# spectral properties of the shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $E = \ell^2$, and consider the multiplication operator $M$:
$$Mx = (\alpha_1x_1,\dots,\alpha_nx_n,\dots), \forall x\in E$$
where $(\alpha_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

And consider the right shift operator $S_r:(x_1,x_2,\dots)\to(0,x_1,x_2)$

Assume $\alpha_n\to \alpha$, as $n\to\infty$. Prove that the spectrum of $S_r\circ M$
$$\sigma(S_r\circ M) = [-|\alpha|,|\alpha|]$$
Here is the solution of the of this problem. I don't know why $M-\alpha I = K$, is compact. And also what is the explict expression of $K_2$. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$
(M-\alpha I)x=(\beta_1x_1,\beta_2x_2,\ldots),
$$
where $\beta_n=\alpha_n-\alpha\to0$. By truncating, you may write $M-\alpha I$ as a limit of finite-rank operators, and that makes it compact.

Then you take $K_2=(\alpha S_r-\lambda I)^{-1}K_1$.