# Brezis' exercise 6.18.10: how to prove that $\sigma (S_r \circ M)=[-|\alpha|, |\alpha|]$ in case $\alpha \neq 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity operator. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E := \ell^2$ with its norm $|\cdot|_2$. An element $x\in E$ is denoted by $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,\ldots)$. Consider the operators
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> S_r x &= (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, \ldots), \\
> S_{\ell} x &= (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_{n+1}, \ldots),
> \end{align*}
> $$
> respectively called the *right shift* and *left shift*.
>
> 1. Determine $\|S_r\|$ and $\|S_{\ell}\|$. Does $S_r$ or $S_{\ell}$ belong to $\mathcal{K}(E)$?
> 2. Prove that $EV(S_r) = \emptyset$.
> 3. Prove that $\sigma\left(S_r\right)=[-1,1]$.
> 4. Prove that $E V (S_{\ell}) = (-1, 1)$. Determine the corresponding eigenspaces.
> 5. Prove that $\sigma(S_{\ell})=[-1,1]$.
> 6. Determine the adjoints $S_r^*$ or $S_{\ell}^*$.
> 7. Prove that for every $\lambda \in(-1,1)$, the spaces $R (S_r-\lambda I)$ and $R (S_{\ell}-\lambda I)$ are closed. Give an explicit representation of these spaces.
> 8. Prove that the spaces $R(S_r \pm I)$ and $R(S_{\ell} \pm I)$ are dense and that they are not closed.
>
> Consider the multiplication operator $M$ defined by
> $$
> M x = (\alpha_1 x_1, \alpha_2 x_2, \ldots, \alpha_n x_n, \ldots),
> $$
> where $(\alpha_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> 9. Determine $E V (S_r \circ M)$.
> 10. Assume that $\alpha_n \to \alpha$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that $\sigma (S_r \circ M)=[-|\alpha|, |\alpha|]$.

Could you explain how to solve (10) in case $\alpha \neq 0$? Below is my failed attempt.

---

We write $S_r M := S_r \circ M$. Then
$$
S_r M x = (0, \alpha_1 x_1, \alpha_2 x_2, \ldots, \alpha_n x_n, \ldots).
$$

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Then
$$
(S_r M - \lambda I) x = (-\lambda x_1, \alpha_1 x_1 - \lambda x_2, \alpha_2 x_2 - \lambda x_3, \ldots, \alpha_n x_n - \lambda x_{n+1}, \ldots).
$$

- $\alpha=0$.

Then $M$ and thus $S_r M$ are compact operators by [exercise 6.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713895/brezis-exercise-6-1-a-compact-operator-in-ellp) (in the same book). Because $\dim E = \infty$, it follows from *Theorem 6.8* (in the same book) that $0 \in \sigma (S_r M)$ and $\sigma (S_r M) \setminus \{0\} = EV (S_r M) \setminus \{0\}$. By (9), we have $EV (S_r M) \subset \{0\}$. Then $\sigma (S_r M) = \{0\}$.

- $\alpha \neq 0$.

Clearly, $M - \alpha I$ is compact.

Comment: Hi @Akira, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2995815/121671) may be what you are looking for

Comment: @Mittens My below attempt for the case $0<|\lambda| \le |\alpha|$ is different and simpler than the solution given by Brezis. Could you please check if I made some subtle mistakes?

Comment: Will do a little later…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we consider the case $|\lambda| > |\alpha|$. Then $T :=\alpha S_r- \lambda I$ is bijective by (3). Then $T^{-1} \in \mathcal L(E)$ by open mapping theorem. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
S_rM - \lambda I &= S_r ( \underbrace{M-\alpha I}_{K}) + \alpha S_r - \lambda I \\
&= S_rK + T \\
&\overset{(*)}{=} T(I + \underbrace{T^{-1} S_r K}_{K_1}) \\
&= T(I+K_1).
\end{align*}
$$

Clearly, $K$ and thus $K_1$ are compact. Our goal is to prove that $S_rM - \lambda I$ is bijective. Because $T$ is invertible, it suffices to prove that $I+K_1$ is bijective. By [Fredholm alternative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722636/is-this-generalization-of-fredholm-alternative-true), it suffices to prove that $I+ K_1$ is injective. Because $T$ is invertible, it suffices to prove that $S_rM - \lambda I$ is injective. This is indeed true by (9) where I showed that $EV (S_r M) \subset \{0\}$.

Second, we consider the case $0<|\lambda| \le |\alpha|$. Then $T$ is injective but not surjective by (2, 3). Then there is a (not necessarily continuous) injective linear map $\tilde T^{-1} : R(T) \to E$ such that $\tilde T^{-1} T = I$. As in $(*)$, we have
$$
S_rM - \lambda I \overset{(**)}{=} T(I + \tilde T^{-1} S_r K).
$$

Clearly, $R(S_rM - \lambda I) \subset R(T) \subsetneq E$. Then $S_rM - \lambda I$ is not surjective. This completes the proof.

---

**Update:** I have found a critical mistake in my proof for the case $0<|\lambda| \le |\alpha|$, i.e., we have $\tilde T^{-1} T = I$ but I incorrectly used $T\tilde T^{-1} = I$ in $(**)$. Below is Brezis' proof.

> Second, we consider the case $0<|\lambda| \le |\alpha|$. Assume the contrary that $S_rM - \lambda I = S_r (M - \alpha I)+ \alpha S_r - \lambda I = S_rK +T$ is bijective. Then
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> T &= (S_rM - \lambda I) - S_r K \\
> &= (S_rM - \lambda I) ( I - \underbrace{(S_rM - \lambda I)^{-1} S_r K}_{K_2}).
> \end{align*}
> $$
>
> Clearly, $K$ and thus $K_2$ are compact. Because $S_rM - \lambda I$ is bijective, we get
>
> - $T$ is injective IFF $I-K_2$ is injective.
> - $T$ is surjective IFF $I-K_2$ is surjective.
>
> By [Fredholm alternative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722636/is-this-generalization-of-fredholm-alternative-true), $I-K_2$ is injective IFF $I-K_2$ is surjective. It follows that $T$ is injective IFF $T$ is surjective, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Mittens I actually found a silly mistake in my attempt. Please have a look at my update.