# Is it true that $T$ is surjective IFF $T-K$ is surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators.

Let $T\in \mathcal L(E)$ and $K \in \mathcal K(E)$ such that $T$ is injective. In solving [Brezis' exercise 6.18.10](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735390/brezis-exercise-6-18-10-how-to-prove-that-sigma-s-r-circ-m-alpha), I'm thinking of

> $T$ is surjective IFF $T-K$ is surjective.

Could you elaborate on whether above statement is true or not? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What if $T$ is the identity and $K$ is a projector onto some finite dimensional subset?

Comment: @Didier You are right! Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume one has a decomposition $E = V\oplus W$ with $V$ a finite dimensional subspace.
Let $K$ be the projector onto $V$ in the direction of $W$ (which is a compact operator) and $T$ the identity map (which is a bounded operator).
Then for any $u = v + w \in E$, $(T-K)(u) = u-v = w \in W$, and therefore, $T$ has range in $W$ and cannot be surjective.