# Brezis' exercise 6.19: prove that $\sigma(T) = \sigma(T^*)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $E, F$ be real Banach spaces. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\sigma(T) = \sigma(T^*)$.
> 2. Give examples showing that there is no general inclusion relation between $E V(T)$ and $E V(T^*)$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

We need two results from the same book, i.e.,

> Let $A: D(A) \subset E \to F$ be an unbounded linear operator that is densely defined and has a closed graph.
>
> **Theorem 2.20.** The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (a) $A$ is surjective, i.e., $R(A)=F$,
> - (b) there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
>   |v| \leq C |A^* v| \quad \forall v \in D (A^*),
>   $$
> - (c) $N (A^*) = \{0\}$ and $R(A^*)$ is closed.
>
> **Theorem 2.21.** The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (a) $A^*$ is surjective, i.e., $R(A^*)=E^*$,
> - (b) there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
>   |u| \leq C |A u| \quad \forall u \in D (A),
>   $$
> - (c) $N (A) = \{0\}$ and $R(A)$ is closed.

1. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. By *Theorem 2.20* and *Theorem 2.21*, $T+\lambda I$ is bijective IFF $(T+\lambda I)^* = T^*+\lambda I$ is bijective. The claim then follows.
2. Let $E := \ell^2$ with its canonical norm $|\cdot|_2$. An element $x\in E$ is denoted by $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,\ldots)$. Consider the operators
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   S_r x &= (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, \ldots), \\
   S_{\ell} x &= (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_{n+1}, \ldots),
   \end{align*}
   $$
   respectively called the *right shift* and *left shift*. From [exercise 6.18](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735390/brezis-exercise-6-18-10-how-to-prove-that-sigma-s-r-circ-m-alpha) in the same book, we have

- $S_r$ and $S_\ell$ are adjoints of each other.
- $EV(S_r) = \emptyset$ and $E V (S_{\ell}) = (-1, 1)$.

Comment: To finish (2) you should compute the $EV$ of $S_r$ and $S_\ell$. The argument for (1) works, but as a matter of style using a theorem that hides all the substance of the proof into a black box, it less elegant than a proof that exposes what is important for the result to hold.

Comment: You say these are **real** Banach spaces.  Does that mean $\rho(T)$ and $\sigma(T)$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$?  Normally, I would expect $\sigma(T)$ to include complex values, and then $\sigma(T^*) = \overline{\sigma(T)}$.  I suppose for **real** operators, the set $\sigma(T)$ is invariant under conjugation, and that is what Brezis intends?

Comment: @GEdgar Yess, $\rho (T)$ and $\sigma (T)$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$.